# C++: Class member reference validity?

Tags: c++, reference

```
Class A
    {
     A(int& foo) : m_foo(foo) {}

     int& m_foo;
    };


int main(void)
{
 A* bar = 0;
 {
   int var = 5;
   bar = new A(var);
 }
 std::cout << "Is m_foo still valid?:" << bar.m_foo << std::endl;
}
```

"m_foo" is a reference and "var" is a local variable which is given to the constructor. "var" gets out of the scope before printing the value so does it make m_foo also invalid?

If m_foo is a pointer, then it would be invalid but does it work the same way with references?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`m_foo` is not valid when `int var` falls out of scope.  The *thing* to which it refers has gone away.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, a reference member becomes invalid if referenced object gets de-allocated. Same as with pointers. If you intend to keep references, make sure the lifetimes nest. Or use something like `boost::weak_ptr`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  The behaviour is undefined.