# Overloaded operator* (multiplication) returning different result

Tags: c++

I created `class Matrix` and overloaded `operator*` for matrix multiplication. Inside the operator the calculations are correct but the returned result is different than this.

I tried changing this function from a friend function to a method but I got the same result. 
Moreover I overloaded operators like +, - and they work fine

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

template<typename T> class Matrix;
template<typename T> Matrix<T> operator * (const Matrix<T>&, const Matrix<T>&);

template <typename T> class Matrix
{
public:
    T *arr = nullptr;
    int r, c;
    friend Matrix<T> operator * <> (const Matrix<T>&, const Matrix<T>&);

    Matrix(T *a, int r, int c)  //parametrized constructor
    {
        this->arr = a;
        this->r = r;
        this->c = c;
    }

    void Print()
    {
        for(int i=0; i<r; i++)
        {
            std::cout<<"|";
            for(int j=0; j<c; j++)
            {
                std::cout<<*(this->arr+i*c+j)<<" ";
            }

            std::cout<<'\b';
            std::cout<<"|";
            std::cout<<std::endl;
        }
        std::cout<<std::endl;
    }

};

template <typename T> Matrix<T> operator * (const Matrix<T> &M1, const Matrix<T> &M2)
{
        int r = M2.r;
        int c = M1.c;
        int l = M1.r;
        T arr[r*c];
        for(int i=0; i<r; i++)
        {
            for(int j=0; j<c; j++)
            {
                arr[i*r+j]=0;
                for(int k=0; k<l; k++)
                {
                    arr[i*r+j]+=(M1.arr[k*r+j]*M2.arr[i*l+k]);
                }
                std::cout<<std::endl;
            }
        }
    //Matrix<T> x(arr, r, c);
    //x.Print();       -this returns correct matrix
    return Matrix<T>(arr, r, c);
}
```

Main

```
int main()
{
    //here I created matrixes a and b but skipped this part of code
    Matrix<int> c = a*b;
    c.Print();  // - this returns wrong matrix
}
```

As you can see, `c` and `x` are matrices created from the same data, but I'm getting two different results.

```
|22 28|
|49 64|
```

from `x.Print()`, and

```
|4761920 4557403|
|4199040 7011960|
```

from `c.Print()`.

Comment: Until you implement proper copy semantics for `Matrix`, i.e. a copy constructor, assignment operator, and destructor, you won't / can't make further progress.  You're returning a `Matrix<T>` by value in the `operator *`, and to return by value requires the object to have correct copy semantics.  Also your `+` and other operators are **not** working fine if you have not implemented copy semantics (assuming you're returning a `Matrix<T>` by value there also).

Comment: You could use a vector to store the data and you'd be fine.

Comment: @OP Yes, a `std::vector` would alleviate all of those other functions being implemented.  But if you insist on using `T *arr` instead of `std::vector<T> arr`, then you will need to put the extra work in correcting the mistakes.  Also `T arr[r*c];` is **not** valid C++.  This is where you should be using `std::vector`.

Comment: It is an almost certainty the only reason the `+` and other operators appear to work fine is because of [nasal demons](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-d&q=nasal+demons).

Comment: [Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198711/c-class-member-reference-validity) but using a reference to a local instead of a pointer.

Answer (score 5):

The issue is that the `Matrix` constructor retains a pointer to an object that's allocated on the stack (`arr`).  Once `arr` goes out of scope, any attempt to dereference the pointer will result in [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You need to find a different way to manage the lifetime of the matrix data (for example, by having the matrix class keep its own copy of it).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for answers, it let me (at least partially) understand this situation.

Changing `T *arr` to `std::vector<T> arr` solved the problem.